# How to test Admob in real device if without Ad unit id

Tags: android, google-play-services, ads

I am trying to use Google mobile ads, how can I test my application if I do not have AdUnitId which you have to pay to get? can I test it on real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to pay to open admob account.
But, if you still want to test without an account, add your device ID to the adrequest, and you will see demo ads.

Comment: when register to admob, have to create AdSense that needs pay

Comment: You dont need to pay anything, they supposed to pay you

Comment: Thanks for your patient answer!

Comment: Warning - if you add your own device id and give the app to other people they will see real live ads - not test ads!

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE:**

Creating an admob account is free. However, you can use these dummy adunit IDS for testing:

**Banner :**    `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`

[Source](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

**Interstitial:** `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`

[Source](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/InterstitialExample/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml)

You can also add emulator and actual device ids for testing:

```
   AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This way your account won't be flagged for invalid clicks that leads to bans.

Comment: Yes, you do need to set the device ID to enable test ads. But the question here is how can someone test Admob without an Ad Unit ID. This answer just states how to setup device IDs for testing. But it does not mention what someone would use for an ad unit ID if they dont want to add use one from their Admob account. E.g. in a sample project that they share with a tutorial.

Comment: @JimRange The question was how to test ads without paying for an adunit. Creating an admob account is free so I assumed that part had been answered already. I've updated my answer

Comment: Ok, I see your perspective. I bumped your answer back up. I originally found this question while trying to find a way to show test ads without configuring IDs, such as for a demo that I can distribute. After re-reading the body of the original question, I now see that your answer could have been helpful to the user, even though it wasn't useful to me before you added the test IDs. Thanks for adding those.