# How i get live admob id to my android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, admob

**activity_main.xml**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;
private Button btnFullscreenAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Read this [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

To set the ad unit id of your ad you want to display to your live id from [Admob](https://apps.admob.com/), add this line of code before you create an ad request and load an ad: `bannerAd.setAdUnitId(YOUR_LIVE_AD_UNIT_ID);`. Change the YOUR_LIVE_AD_UNIT_ID to your ad unit id from your admob ad unit.

If you want to test your ads, you shouldn't use your live id until you are publishing your app. For Banner Ads, use `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111` and for interstitial ads, use `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you just tell him to use your ad IDs so you'd get his ad revenue? :O Besides last sentence everything was OK.

Comment: @goobliata no look at the second answer on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268888/how-to-test-admob-in-real-device-if-without-ad-unit-id)

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now!